# Filling rows between two values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
    df<-structure(list(StimulusName = c("Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", 
"Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", 
"Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", 
"Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", 
"Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", "Alpha5", 
"Alpha5", "Alpha5"), Label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Onset", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Offset", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Onset", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Offset", NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to fill the rows *between* each occurrence of `Onset` and `Offset` with the word 'Onset' in the column `Label`. The final dataframe would look like this:

```
    StimulusName Label
1   Alpha5       NA
2   Alpha5       NA
3   Alpha5       NA
4   Alpha5       NA
5   Alpha5       NA
6   Alpha5       Onset
7   Alpha5       Onset
8   Alpha5       Onset
9   Alpha5       Onset
10  Alpha5       Onset
11  Alpha5       Onset
12  Alpha5       Offset
13  Alpha5       NA
14  Alpha5       NA
15  Alpha5       NA
16  Alpha5       NA
17  Alpha5       NA
18  Alpha5       NA
19  Alpha5       NA
20  Alpha5       Onset
21  Alpha5       Onset
22  Alpha5       Onset
23  Alpha5       Onset
24  Alpha5       Onset
25  Alpha5       Onset
26  Alpha5       Onset
27  Alpha5       Onset
28  Alpha5       Onset
29  Alpha5       Offset
30  Alpha5       NA
31  Alpha5       NA
32  Alpha5       NA
33  Alpha5       NA
```

Can this be achieved in `dplyr` using `fill()`?

This code obviously doesn't work as it fills in everything after the first non `NA` value:

```
Test <- df%>% 
  fill(df$Label)
```

I'm open to any solution but would prefer to use `dplyr` and avoid loops where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` way to do it,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Label))) %>% 
 mutate(Label = replace(Label, first(Label) == 'Onset', 'Onset')) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

Comment: I found this solution to work best. When I tried to scale up a previous answer I had accepted it wasn't working as intended, however this one scaled up nicely.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this using base R `mapply`

```
#Get "Onset" indices
onset_ind <- which(df$Label == "Onset")

#Get "Offset" indices
offset_ind <- which(df$Label == "Offset")

#Create a sequence of indices between onset and offset and change their value
df$Label[unlist(mapply(function(x, y) x:y, onset_ind, offset_ind - 1))] <- "Onset"

df
#   StimulusName  Label
#1        Alpha5   <NA>
#2        Alpha5   <NA>
#3        Alpha5   <NA>
#4        Alpha5   <NA>
#5        Alpha5   <NA>
#6        Alpha5  Onset
#7        Alpha5  Onset
#8        Alpha5  Onset
#9        Alpha5  Onset
#10       Alpha5  Onset
#11       Alpha5  Onset
#12       Alpha5 Offset
#13       Alpha5   <NA>
#14       Alpha5   <NA>
#.....
```

Here it assumes that number of "Onset" and "Offset" occurrence is the same.

---

If you want to avoid unnecessary variable creation (`onset_ind` and `offset_ind`) you can do this in one-line

```
df$Label[unlist(mapply(function(x, y) x:y, 
      which(df$Label == "Onset"), which(df$Label == "Offset") - 1))] <- "Onset"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo) #using na.locf()

df2<-data.frame(df) # converting list to data frame

df2$Label[which((is.na(df2$Label)& !is.na(na.locf(df2)[,2]) & na.locf(df2)[,2]=="Offset")=="FALSE")]<-
  na.locf(df2)[,2][which((is.na(df2$Label)& !is.na(na.locf(df2)[,2]) & na.locf(df2)[,2]=="Offset")=="FALSE")]

df2
StimulusName  Label
1        Alpha5   <NA>
2        Alpha5   <NA>
3        Alpha5   <NA>
4        Alpha5   <NA>
5        Alpha5   <NA>
6        Alpha5  Onset
7        Alpha5  Onset
8        Alpha5  Onset
9        Alpha5  Onset
10       Alpha5  Onset
11       Alpha5  Onset
12       Alpha5 Offset
13       Alpha5   <NA>
14       Alpha5   <NA>
15       Alpha5   <NA>
16       Alpha5   <NA>
17       Alpha5   <NA>
18       Alpha5   <NA>
19       Alpha5   <NA>
20       Alpha5  Onset
21       Alpha5  Onset
22       Alpha5  Onset
23       Alpha5  Onset
24       Alpha5  Onset
25       Alpha5  Onset
26       Alpha5  Onset
27       Alpha5  Onset
28       Alpha5  Onset
29       Alpha5 Offset
30       Alpha5   <NA>
31       Alpha5   <NA>
32       Alpha5   <NA>
33       Alpha5   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a user-defined function.

```
 for(i in 1:length(df$Label)){    
   if(df$Label[i]%in%"Onff"==TRUE)    
   {if(df$Label[i+1]%in%NA==TRUE){df$Label[i+1]<-"Onff"}}    
     else{df$Label[i]<-df$Label[i]}    
 }
```